# Automate Angular 6 builds on IBM Cloud

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud, angular-cli

I'm developing an Angular 6 app that's hosted on IBM Cloud. Sometimes I forget to run the "ng build" command from Angular-cli and I have to re-deploy the app. Is there some way of automating the process in e.g. the delivery pipeline so IBM Cloud always runs the "ng build"-command with every build before deploying the app?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/content/code/tool_jenkins/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you have deployed the app to Cloud Foundry or Kubernetes?

You can adopt a DevOps approach by using Cloud Continuous Delivery, which includes open toolchains that automate the building and deployment of applications. You can get started by creating a simple deployment toolchain that supports development, deployment, and operations tasks.

In the **Build** phase of the delivery pipeline, you can select npm as your builder type, add `npm run-script build` command to build your Angular 6 app.

Adding a toolchain to an existing app is easier and is just a click of a button as mentioned in the [link here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/tutorials/add-a-toolchain-to-an-app?task=2)